# Running test on substrate throws Every active pallet has a name in the runtime

Tags: rust, substrate

`mock.rs` file

```rust
use crate as pallet_my;
use sp_core::H256;
use frame_support::parameter_types;
use sp_runtime::{
    traits::{BlakeTwo256, IdentityLookup}, testing::Header,
};
use frame_system as system;

type UncheckedExtrinsic = frame_system::mocking::MockUncheckedExtrinsic<Test>;
type Block = frame_system::mocking::MockBlock<Test>;

// Configure a mock runtime to test the pallet.
frame_support::construct_runtime!(
    pub enum Test where
        Block = Block,
        NodeBlock = Block,
        UncheckedExtrinsic = UncheckedExtrinsic,
    {
        System: frame_system::{Module, Call, Config, Storage, Event<T>},
        MyModule: pallet_my::{Module, Call, Storage, Event<T>},
    }
);

parameter_types! {
    pub const BlockHashCount: u64 = 250;
    pub const SS58Prefix: u8 = 42;
}

impl frame_system::Config for Test {
    type BaseCallFilter = ();
    type BlockWeights = ();
    type BlockLength = ();
    type DbWeight = ();
    type Origin = Origin;
    type Call = Call;
    type Index = u64;
    type BlockNumber = u64;
    type Hash = H256;
    type Hashing = BlakeTwo256;
    type AccountId = u64;
    type Lookup = IdentityLookup<Self::AccountId>;
    type Header = Header;
    type Event = Event;
    type BlockHashCount = BlockHashCount;
    type Version = ();
    type PalletInfo = PalletInfo;
    type AccountData = ();
    type OnNewAccount = ();
    type OnKilledAccount = ();
    type SystemWeightInfo = ();
    type SS58Prefix = SS58Prefix;

}
parameter_types! {
    pub const MinimumPeriod: u64 = 5;
}

impl pallet_timestamp::Config for Test {
    type Moment = u64;
    type OnTimestampSet = ();
    type MinimumPeriod = ();
    type WeightInfo = ();
}

impl pallet_my::Config for Test {
    type Event = Event;
    type TimeProvider = pallet_timestamp::Pallet<Test>;
}

// Build genesis storage according to the mock runtime.
pub fn new_test_ext() -> sp_io::TestExternalities {
    system::GenesisConfig::default().build_storage::<Test>().unwrap().into()
}
```

`tests.rs`  file

```rust
use super::*;
use crate::mock::new_test_ext;
use crate::mock::Origin;

use frame_support::{assert_ok};
use crate::mock::MyModule;
#[test]
fn check_doc_insertion() {

    new_test_ext().execute_with(||{
        assert_ok!(
            MyModule::insert_my_document(Origin::signed(1), vec![1,2,3,4], vec![1,2])
        );
    });
}
```

`lib.rs` file Pallet config declaration

```rust
    #[pallet::config]
    pub trait Config: frame_system::Config + pallet_timestamp::Config {
        type Event: From<Event<Self>> + IsType<<Self as frame_system::Config>::Event>;
        type TimeProvider: UnixTime;
    }
```

insert function

```
#[pallet::weight(0)]
        pub fn insert_my_document(
            origin: OriginFor<T>,
            my_document: Vec<u8>,
            my_hash: Vec<u8>,
        ) -> DispatchResultWithPostInfo {

            let origin_account = ensure_signed(origin)?;

            let block_number = <frame_system::Module<T>>::block_number();

            let time = T::TimeProvider::now().as_secs();


            myDocument::<T>::insert(
                my_hash.clone(),
                my {
                    my_uri: None,
                    my_document,
                    block_number,
                    block_time_stamp: time,
                    my_ref: None,
                    sender_account_id: origin_account.clone(),
                    active: Some(true)
                }
            );

            Self::deposit_event(Event::myDocumentCreated(my_hash, origin_account));

            Ok(().into())
        }
    }
```

Test throws an error saying

```
Every active pallet has a name in the runtime; qed
thread 'tests::check_doc_insertion' panicked at 'Every active pallet has a name in the runtime; qed'
```

How to fix this issue?

Comment: Hi Co2f2e, Can you please support our Substrate StackExchange proposal: https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/126136

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add `pallet_timestamp` to your `construct_runtime!`.

```
// Configure a mock runtime to test the pallet.
frame_support::construct_runtime!(
    pub enum Test where
        Block = Block,
        NodeBlock = Block,
        UncheckedExtrinsic = UncheckedExtrinsic,
    {
        System: frame_system::{Module, Call, Config, Storage, Event<T>},
        Timestamp: pallet_timestamp::{Pallet, Call, Storage, Inherent},
        MyModule: pallet_my::{Module, Call, Storage, Event<T>},
    }
);
```

Basically, we now expect that every pallet be included in the `construct_runtime!`, which generates a `Pallet` struct and some of the things like a name for the pallet for the internal metadata.

Because you are using the Timestamp pallet, but did not properly include it into your runtime, you get this error.